# Can an ImageChooser only show images of certain dimensions

Tags: django, wagtail

Some parts of my site are branding and the images should only be of particular dimensions.

Is it possible to have the ImageChooser only display images of a certain dimension ?

In a previous question @Alexy showed how the ImageField clean method can be used to only allow certain images 
[Can a wagtail ImageField be restricted to by image dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366684/can-a-wagtail-imagefield-be-restricted-to-by-image-dimension)

But to be more user friendly, I'd like the ImageChooser to only display suitable images in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a subclass of `ImageChooserBlock`, and override the [`field` property](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/3191849b6b28b9b85bdcf639b43955d882e0322f/wagtail/core/blocks/field_block.py#L536-L540) of `ChooserBlock` to filter the images available in the choice field:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class SmallImageChooserBlock(ImageChooserBlock):

    @cached_property
    def field(self):
        # Filter the choice field to include only images with 
        # width 100 and height 100
        return forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=self.target_model.objects.filter(width=100, height=100), 
            widget=self.widget, 
            required=self._required, 
            help_text=self._help_text
        )
```

Then use this block to render the content panel for that field.

Comment: Thanks this looks like exactly what I need...  S/O says I can award the bounty in 2h.

Answer (score 1):

You could rig up something pretty easily using Django's signals to create width/height tags whenever you upload an image. It would look something like this:

```
# signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from wagtail.images.models import Image


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Image)
def create_image_dimension_tags(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        image = kwargs.get('instance')
        height = image.file.height
        width = image.file.width
        image.tags.create(name=f'{height}h')
        image.tags.create(name=f'{width}w')
```

A 100x100 image would then have a `100w` tag and a `100h` tag you could use to filter the uploaded images.

Comment: Thanks for having a go at this, I considered something like this, but it seemed like there must be a way using the info already in wagtail, which is what the other answer does.